# gitlab error during commit: invalid cross-device link

Tags: git, gitlab, rhel7, cross-device

I'm trying to commit changes in Gitlab repo (gui). Following error ocurred for such action:

```
2:update reference: migrating quarantined objects: migrating directory "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/+gitaly/tmp(...)" finalizing object file: rename "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/+gitaly/tmp(...)": invalid cross-device link.
```

I don't know why it does not work.

env:
gitlab 15.1
rhel7

Comment: You can view this link may be help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79132/invalid-cross-device-link-while-hardlinking-in-the-same-file-system

Comment: That's definitely odd, but probably some kind of GitLab setup error: Git tries to create the temporary quarantine area on the same file system as the main repository by using the repository's directory to hold the quarantined files. You might expand on your GitLab setup.